# Hibernate Search + Infinispan + JGroups -> not all events propagate

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search, infinispan, jgroups

I'm using the above combination to cluster my Hibernate Search nodes. What I noticed is that when I update an entity and save the changes, the Hibernate Search entity listener is called and the changes gets propagated to other nodes, i.e. if I run a full text query on the other node after the update, I can see the changes to the entity. But it's not the case when I create an new entity and persist into the database (using Spring Data JPA repository). In this case the Hibernate Search entity listener is called again, but the entity is visible only on node1 until I restart node2, i.e. if I run the same full text query on both nodes, only the one on node1 will return it. After restarting the other node it picks up the new entity.

I'm using the default configuration, the nodes connect to each other using TCPPing.

Any idea where should I look? How could I find out what's happening?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by creating an entity (I guess it's not just instantiation of the object ;-))? Example code could be useful.

Comment: What do you mean by "is visible" ? by running a full-text query it's not being found?

Comment: Sorry for the sloppy description, I updated it. Code sample would be indeed nice, but I need more time to strip it down to a digestible  example.

Comment: It was a user error. I was confused by the fact that both Hibernate Search and Infinispan used JGroups and did not realize that I need two separate configuration for them.